# Book about a girl who could talk to animals

Tags: story-identification, novel

When I was in middle school (early/mid 90's) there was a book about a girl that could talk to animals. She would only be able to speak to them in her head and she would have to quiet her heart to hear them. She would quiet her heart so much that she would almost stop it and would pass out.

I know there were mythical creatures, they were trying to get to a castle or something, but beyond that, I don't remember much other than I loved the book!

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Comment: Could she also grunt and squeak and squawk with the animals?

Answer (score 4):

This is [*Wild Magic*](http://tamorapierce.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_Magic), the first book in the *Immortals Quartet* by Tamora Pierce (part of her Tortall series).

Summary:

> Young Daine's knack with animals gets her a job helping the royal
>   horse mistress drive a herd of ponies to Tortall. It soon becomes
>   clear that Daine's talent, despite her struggles to hide it, is
>   downright magical. Horses and other animals not only obey the
>   mysterious girl, they come to her and seem to listen to her words. But
>   Daine will have to trust humans before she can come to terms with her
>   powers, her past and herself.

There are griffins, dragons, and various other mythological creatures. In the first book they head towards two castles--the royal palace in Corus, and Pirate's Swoop, which is a seaside estate that the finale chapters take place in.

Daine tries to talk/listen to the dolphins far out in the sea. It...doesn't work.

> Daine grabbed her hand. “You're the purple fire. You brought me back?”
>
> “I gave you a direct jolt to the heart. We thought we'd lost you."
>
> “My heart?” She frowned, remembering. “It made too much noise. I
>   wanted it to quiet down so I could talk with the dolphins.”
>
> “Do you hear her?” Numair asked the clouds. "She wanted to talk to
>   dolphins, so she stopped her own blessed heart! Mithros, Mynoss, and
>   Shakith!”
>
> Daine sat up. “I never.”
>
> Numair opened his mouth and Onua, behind him, covered it. “Not until
>   you can talk without screaming," she said firmly.
>
> "Daine, meditation is done for control over body responses, and thus
>   over mind.” Alanna's purple eyes were amused, but serious as well. “In
>   cutting back the sound of your heart, you were cutting the heartbeat
>   itself.”