# Old fantasy book/series about mages in which the main character stops her heart through meditation

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I’m looking for a fantasy series/book I read when I was younger, over a decade ago—I don’t remember much about it, so bear with me.

It followed a female protagonist who was a mage or in training to become a mage, and there was a romance with her male teacher. The one scene I vividly remember from the book is that through meditation (they were by a lake, resting after part of their journey) she slowed down her heart enough that it stopped—and her teacher had to revive her.

I remember reading this in a mass market book format, and the cover was an older type of design. I know this isn’t a lot to go on, but hopefully someone else out there remembers the meditation-heart-stopping scene, too…

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Note that I removed the [fantasy-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/632) tag, as it's meant for questions about the fantasy genre in general, rather than questions about specific stories.

Comment: My first thought was *Circle of Magic* by Tamora Pierce with Tris, but she makes a different mistake with her heart (she takes in tidal energy with each heartbeat and it explodes the rock she's on) and there's no romance with her teacher.

Comment: @Hannah: Right author, wrong book. ^_^ Although Numair is the teacher in both cases. You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Numair and Niko aren't the same person - I don't think there are any explicit crossovers between the Tortall books and the Circle books, they're set in different worlds as far as I know.

Comment: @Showsni It has been several years since I read either series. I acknowledge my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Tamora Pierce's *[Wild Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13836.Wild_Magic)*, first book of the *The Immortals* series, Daine is trying to talk to some dolphins, and decides that her heart is too loud, so she stops it, forcing Numair, her teacher (and future husband) to restart her heart with lightning magic.

> Numair shook Daine as he held her. "You fiend!" he yelled.
> "What on earth possessed you? You were dead & I ought to kill you
> myself!"
> "Numair, calm down." The Lioness bent over Daine, looking white
> and drawn. "How are you, youngling? You gave us a scare."
> Daine grabbed her hand. "You're the purple fire. You brought me
> back?"
> "I gave you a direct jolt to the heart. We thought we'd lost
> you."
> "My heart?" She frowned, remembering. "It made too much noise.
> I wanted it to quiet down so I could talk with the dolphins."

Found with a search for `novel mage meditating accidentally stops her heart`, which led me to the [Master of Your Own Domain](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MasterofYourDomain) page on TV Tropes.

It's had a variety of covers, but I suspect the "older type of design" suggests the 1997 one.

[image: Front cover of Wild Magic]

Comment: Unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204397/, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230462/, and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190496/, which also mentions the heart-stopping incident.